# I get the error message: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wrote a function that takes two arrays as arguments.The first one is an array with objects and the second is an array with integers:

```
var employees = [{name:"Ash Ketsup"}, {name:"Fronto"}, {name:"Captain"}];
var employeesAge = [25,30,50];


function addNewProp(arr1,arr2){

if (arr1 instanceof Array && arr2 instanceof Array){

    var data = [];

    for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){

           data[i].push({name:arr1[i].name ,age:arr2[i]});

            }

        };
        return data;
            alert(data);

        }; 

    var check = addNewProp(employees,employeesAge);
    alert(check);
```

All I want is to make an array of objects that they will have the values name and age. But I get the Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error message. I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.
Can you help me out please?

Comment: `data[i].push()` is wrong - you are not calling `push()` on the array (which does have that method) but you're calling `push()` on the member of the array (which doesn't. Or doesn't necessarily, to be more general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
data.push({name:arr1[i].name ,age:arr2[i]});
```

The `data` is an array and it has a function called push. While `data[i]` is the element of the array called `data` in the position with index `i`.

Comment: Thnx a lot for your help @Christos!

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [];
```

it means that data will be length of 0, so you can't get access to it like data[i]. You should use this syntax for it:

```
data.push({ 
    name : arr1[i].name,
    age : arr2[i]
});
```

Comment: @Sergiti I'm glad that my solution helps you